# errorerror: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/CustomActionBarTheme') can't figure out

Tags: android

i just started programming for android and ran into this error which i can't solve.
this is the error i get:

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/CustomActionBarTheme').

i get this error in the file bin/AndroidManifest.xml

i don't see @style/CustomActionBarTheme anywhere so i don't know why i get this error.
if someone could help you'd be my hero!
this is my script:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    </application>
```

Comment: The problem is possibly coming from `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. Try cleaning your project, "Project --> Clean...") and if that doesn't work then post your `styles.xml`

Comment: Go to res-> values->style.xml change  parent="android:Theme.Light" or some other themes.

Answer (score 1):

[Dont delete original styles.xml file] 
copy/revert to the default/original styles.xml file and then you can add your items to that default styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

I originally deleted styles.xml file and paste another, and it was making the same issue, jus go to Project->Clean...